# How to connect to remote mysql server in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

Hi i have a requirement where i need to connect to remote mysql server. My application shall be running on local machine and my mysql will be running on remote server.I have tried the following code:

```
DB = 'gts'
DB_HOST = 'ps95074.dreamhost.com'
DB_USER = 'root'
DB_PASSWORD = 'dbadminpassword'
conn = MySQLdb.Connection(db=DB, host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER,passwd=DB_PASSWORD)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

But i am getting the following error

```
OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'ps95074.dreamhost.com' (1)")
```

Instead if i use

```
DB_HOST='localhost'
```

Everything works fine. How can same be possible with remote host.Any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: See this? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=434155  Maybe a similar issue. You probably need to open a ticket with DreamHost, they may need to install the module or opening the connection.

Comment: This is unrelated to programming, belongs on Dreamhost support forum.

Comment: Since he's connecting as root he might have a dedicated/virtual server. In this case it would belong on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

Check your firewall. That server is online and available from any machines:

```
> mysql -h ps95074.dreamhost.com
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'myhost' (using password: NO)
```

However, even if you can connect chances are good that your database user only allows local connections.

Update: I just tried it again and now it also fails using the commandline client. So clearly something is wrong with your server.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 11.10 and there is no firewall installed.